# How well this ECS implementation follows these principals

Tags: c++, c++11, design-patterns, cpu-cache, entity-component-system

I'm currently learning about Entity-Component-System architecture Data-Driven design as a way to counter bad OOP design and optimize data fetching as a CPU friendly operation.

I'm trying to write a simple ECS system that tries to follows these principals:

- CPU friendly by storing entities/components in contiguous chunk of memory and minimize cache miss
- Not set an upper bound to number of entities/components/systems in the system

My basic implementation so far is as follows:

`Entity` class with a counting `m_ID` member being incremented for each newly created entity.
An `std::vector<Entity*>` for containing children entities.
An `std::vector<bool>` for containing the signature of what components the entity uses. I've chosen `std::vector<bool>` over `std::bitset<S>` since I wish to be able as a requirement to add/remove components in runtime and I do not wish to set an upper-bound to the size of components an entity have so I cannot know size in compile time, so I've decided to use the `std::vector<bool>` specialization that stores each `bool` as 1 bit which save some space and allows for growth.
An `std::unordered_map<unsigned int, unsigned int>` where the key is the component's ID and the value is an index into a `std::vector<unsigned int, std::vector<ComponentBase>>` map of component's ID to components vector residing in `ECSManager` class.

`Component` class with a unique ID per component type using templates to generate a unique `Component<T>::ID` for each component type.

`System` class containing `std::vector<bool>` responsible for holding the signature of what entities the system wants to operate on depends on if they have a sufficient components signature.

Now I'm sure my implementation is not nearly close to what my requirements are, for example I'm not really sure if it's CPU friendly as an ECS should be since I rely heavily on `std::unordered_map` which is implemented by a linked list. But to be honest I'm not sure at all so this is why I'm posting my implementation here hoping for a feedback on what's good and what's not and how I can maybe make it better.

`ComponentBase.h`:

```
#pragma once

#include <atomic>

static std::atomic<unsigned int> s_CurrentId;

class ComponentBase
{
public:
    inline static unsigned GetID() { return ++s_CurrentId; }
};
```

`Component.h`:

```
#pragma once

#include "ComponentBase.h"

template <typename T>
class Component : public ComponentBase
{
public:
    static const unsigned int ID = ComponentBase::GetID();
};
```

`Entity.h`:

```
#pragma once

#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>

class Entity
{
private:
    unsigned int m_Id;
    std::vector<Entity*> m_Children;
    std::vector<bool> m_Signature;
    std::unordered_map<unsigned int, unsigned int> m_ComponentsIndex;
protected:
    Entity();
    friend class ComponentManager;
    friend class Scene;
public:
    Entity(const Entity& other) = delete;
    virtual ~Entity();

    Entity& operator=(const Entity& other) = delete;

    inline unsigned int GetID() { return m_Id; }
    void AddChild(Entity* entity);
    inline const std::vector<Entity*>& GetChildren() const { return m_Children; }
    void AddComponent(unsigned int componentID, unsigned int index);
    void RemoveComponent(unsigned int componentID);
    inline const std::vector<bool>& GetSignature() const { return m_Signature; }
    inline const std::unordered_map<unsigned int, unsigned int>& GetComponentsIndex() const { return m_ComponentsIndex; }
};
```

`Entity.cpp`:

```
#include "Entity.h"

#include <atomic>

static std::atomic<unsigned int> s_CurrentId;

Entity::Entity()
    : m_Id(s_CurrentId++)
{
}

Entity::~Entity()
{
    for (const auto& child : m_Children)
        delete child;
}

void Entity::AddChild(Entity* entity)
{
    m_Children.push_back(entity);
}

void Entity::AddComponent(unsigned int componentID, unsigned int index)
{
    m_Signature[componentID] = true;
    m_ComponentsIndex[componentID] = index;
}

void Entity::RemoveComponent(unsigned int componentID)
{
    m_Signature[componentID] = false;
    m_ComponentsIndex.erase(componentID);
}
```

`System.h`:

```
#pragma once

#include <vector>
#include "Entity.h"

class System
{
private:
    std::vector<bool> m_ComponentIDs;
protected:
    System(std::vector<unsigned int>& componentIDs);
public:
    virtual ~System();

    virtual void Update() = 0;
};
```

`System.cpp`:

```
#include "System.h"

System::System(std::vector<unsigned int>& componentIDs)
{
    for (const auto& componentID : componentIDs)
        m_ComponentIDs[componentID] = true;
}

System::~System()
{
}
```

`ECSManager.h`:

```
#pragma once

#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include "../Entity.h"
#include "ComponentBase.h"

class ECSManager
{
private:
    std::unordered_map<unsigned int, std::vector<ComponentBase>> m_Components;
    std::unordered_map<unsigned int, Entity> m_Entities;
private:
    ECSManager();
public:

    const Entity& CreateEntity()
    {
        Entity e;
        m_Entities.emplace(e.GetID(), std::move(e));
        return m_Entities[e.GetID()];
    }

    template <typename TComponent, typename... Args>
    void AddComponent(unsigned int entityId, Args&&... args)
    {
        unsigned int componentID = TComponent::ID;
        if (m_Components[componentID] == m_Components.end())
            m_Components[componentID] = std::vector<TComponent>();
        m_Components[componentID].push_back(T(std::forward<Args>(args)...));

        m_Entities[entityId].AddComponent(componentID, m_Components[componentID].size() - 1);

        if (m_Signatures[m_Entities[entityId].GetSignature()] == m_Signatures.end())
            m_Signatures[m_Entities[entityId].GetSignature()] = std::vector<unsigned int>();
        m_Signatures[m_Entities[entityId].GetSignature()].push_back(entityId);
    }

    template <typename TComponent>
    TComponent& GetComponent(Entity& entity)
    {
        return m_Components[TComponent::ID][entity.GetComponentsIndex()[TComponent::ID]];
    }

    template <typename TComponent>
    std::vector<TComponent>& GetComponents()
    {
        unsigned int componentID = TComponent::ID;
        return m_Components[componentID];
    }

    std::vector<Entity&> GetEntities(std::vector<bool> componentIDs)
    {
        std::vector<Entity&> entities;
        for (auto& entity : m_Entities)
        {
            const auto& entitySignature = entity.second.GetSignature();
            if (componentIDs.size() > entitySignature.size())
                continue;

            bool equal = true;
            for (std::size_t i = 0; i != componentIDs.size(); i++)
            {
                if (componentIDs[i] & entitySignature[i] == 0)
                {
                    equal = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!equal)
                continue;

            entities.push_back(entity.second);
        }
        return entities;
    }
};
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it would be a better fit on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/